# Can I disable the limbs of an iron golem?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, d20-system

Quite simply, can the individual joints and/or limbs of an Iron Golem (or any other metallic golem) be disabled or otherwise immobilized? Disable Device or *Molecular Bonding* would seem the two most likely methods.

Official WotC d20 sources are viable for my purposes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to immobilize creatures.  For example a [web](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/web.htm) spell does not allow spell resistance, so it will affect an iron golem normally.  An alchemical [tanglefoot bag](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Tanglefoot_Bag) will immobilize a creature on a failed save.  There's also the traditional approach of grappling the golem (or summoning a monster to grapple the golem for you).

None of these methods are specifically targeted at a golem's limbs.  I'm not aware of any official rules for targeting limbs; there appears to be a third-party supplement called [Torn Asunder: Critical Hits](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/27822/Torn-Asunder-Critical-Hits?it=1) which has rules for this, but I haven't read it.

If you can grapple and pin the golem, you might try gluing its arms together using [sovereign glue](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Sovereign_Glue).  Some DMs might require that the golem be helpless for this to work (rather than merely pinned) but others might allow it.

I don't think Disable Device is a good approach here.  Even if the DM allows you to treat a golem as a "device", the disable check would require at least 2d4 rounds, and it's probably not possible to make the check while the golem is moving around.

Comment: shame there's not core rules for disarming and dislegging

Comment: So, in other words, there are no specific rules, but there are effects which could be applied to achieve such a result?